# Jenkins and Kubernetes in the same VM

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I am doing a test here and need to delivery a build, test and deploy pipeline using Jenkins and Kubernetes.

I am using a Mac and created a VM using VirtualBox with Ubuntu 18 and installed Jenkins there.

I installed Kubernetes (minukube) but when I try to start it I receive:

> "This computer doesn't have VT-x/AMD/v enabler. Enabling it in the BIOS
>   is mandatory"

Reading some blogs they said that VM inside VM is not a good architecture.

My question is: what is the best approach to do it and have something to delivery in the end - like a VM or a weblink?

Comment: This could maybe be useful: https://itnext.io/deploy-jenkins-with-dynamic-slaves-in-minikube-8aef5404e9c1

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't put a comment, cause I don't have enough permissions to do so.

This is not related to k8s, your issue most likely is with the virtualization in your PC, you may follow the error you got and try to enable to the VTx/AMD option in the boot.

Comment: In fact this is a limitation of Virtual Box as I see. For MAC I don't have any other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Install minikube in your laptop, then run Jenkins X in minikube and that will give you CI/CD and kubernetes, all in one vm